# Reporting Powershell progress from event handler

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I've written a cmdlet in C# that acts as a wrapper for a heavy/long-running synchronous operation.  The method (someone else' code) reports percentage progress during this long-running operation via event handlers, and I'd like to hook these up to powershell's standard `WriteProgress` method to get the pretty-printed progress bar.  However, I'm getting the following error message:

`The WriteObject and WriteError methods cannot be called from outside the overrides of the BeginProcessing, ProcessRecord, and EndProcessing methods, and they can only be called from within the same thread.`

Here's my code:

```
overrride void ProcessRecord()
{
    LongRunningOperation op = new LongRunningOperation();
    op.ProgressChanged += ProgressUpdate;
    op.Execute();
    op.ProgressChanged -= ProgressUpdate;
}

void ProgressUpdate(object sender, ProgressChangeEventArgs e)
{
   ProgressRecord progress = new ProgressRecord(activityId: 1, activity: "Moving data", statusDescription: "Current operation");
   progress.PercentComplete = e.ProgressPercentage;
   WriteProgress(progress);
}
```

Anyone able to spot what I'm doing wrong?

**Update:** Looks like the event handler is being triggered from a different thread than `ProcessRecord()`.  How can I get the information I need back into the same thread as `ProcessRecord()`?

Comment: Are you sure that `op.ProgressChanged` raised in the same thread as `op.Execute()` called?

Comment: @PetSerAl Whelp, that appears to be problem the (a?) problem.  Didn't think op.Execute() would spin up some new threads.  Any idea how to resolve that?

Comment: What PowerShell and .NET version are you targeting?

Comment: PowerShell 3, .NET 4.5

Comment: Does is make a difference if you register a lambda/delegate to the event, rather than an instance method?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Same error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually marshal `ProgressChanged` event handler back to PowerShell pipeline thread. It can be done by applying producer–consumer pattern where `ProgressChanged` event handler will be producer and event loop in PowerShell pipeline thread will be consumer. It can be easy implemented with support of [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd267312.aspx) introduced in .NET Framework 4.0:

```
overrride void ProcessRecord() {
    Task longRunningOperation;
    using(BlockingCollection<ProgressRecord> queue = new BlockingCollection<ProgressRecord>()) {
        //offload LongRunningOperation to different thread to keep control on PowerShell pipeline thread
        longRunningOperation=Task.Run(() => {
            try {
                //replace EventHandler<ProgressChangeEventArgs> with ProgressChanged type
                EventHandler<ProgressChangeEventArgs> handler =
                    //implemented as anonymous method to capture queue local variable
                    (object sender, ProgressChangeEventArgs e) => {
                        ProgressRecord progress = new ProgressRecord(activityId: 1, activity: "Moving data", statusDescription: "Current operation");
                        progress.PercentComplete = e.ProgressPercentage;
                        //queue ProgressRecord for processing in PowerShell pipeline thread
                        queue.Add(progress);
                    }
                LongRunningOperation op = new LongRunningOperation();
                op.ProgressChanged += handler;
                op.Execute();
                op.ProgressChanged -= handler;
            } finally {
                queue.CompleteAdding();
            }
        });
        //event loop
        for(;;) {
            ProgressRecord progress;
            if(!queue.TryTake(out progress, Timeout.Infinite)) {
                break;
            }
            WriteProgress(progress);
        }
    }
    //get any exception from LongRunningOperation
    longRunningOperation.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```